# How to publish a Flutter app, created in Android Studio, in the Apple app store

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, publishing

I have developed a Flutter app in Android Studio (running on a Windows computer) and have successfully published it in the Google Play store. I would also like to publish the same app in Apple's app store but can't seem to find instructions on how to do this.

I do not own a Apple computer but if that is the only way forward I can look into purchasing one.

The last thing I want to do is to rewrite the app in another language (e.g. Swift).

Can't image being the first person wanting to do this but I can't find any info on the net. Can someone tell me what to do or point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: See this documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Answer (score 0):

Well, the language won't really matter. The main step in publishing your app to the app store is making the app archive which you can do only in Xcode, for which you will need a Mac.

Comment: Ok, so would I be able to port my hard work in Android Studio to Xcode assuming that I would buy a Mac computer?

Comment: There is no need to port, Making an archive is just an additional step which is specific to ios publishing. In short, yes you would be able to.

Comment: Sorry for being so thick but how would this work?
Should I:
1. Export Android Studio project to ZIP file in windows;
2. Install Android Studio on MAC and import this ZIP file;
3. Build iOS with Android Studio on MAC......
..... and how would I get this into Xcode to publish?
As you can see I am not a MAC user...but willing to learn.
Thanks for you time.

Comment: No, not at all. You dont have to think of it as an approach where you transfer files to make the app cross platform, the flutter project you have is already ios enabled and no extra files are to be transferred in or out of it. If you notice there is an ios folder in your project structure, that is all you need to make a build for ios. Once you have Xcode, you have to open a file called Runner.xcworkspace (in the ios folder) in xcode, then follow some steps for publishing. Steps are here https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#review-xcode-project-settings

Comment: I see, will certainly try that but I guess I am off to the stores to buy some Apple gear first after the current lockdown is over. In the mean time, thanks for your kind help and I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Sure, Be safe and Do share how app publishing goes :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to options: purchase a Mac or rent it online. There are webs that offers this kind of service and I think this is a good option if you’re not sure if it’s worth to invest on Apple machine at this time.